# destructured items not found when destructuring an enum inside a macro

Tags: rust, enums, macros, destructuring, rust-macros

```rust
macro_rules! declare_types {
    ($($token:ident -> $inner:ty, $to_string:expr,)*) => {
        enum Value {
            $($token($inner),)*
        }

        impl Display for Value {
            fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), fmt::Error> {
                match self {
                    $(
                        Self::$token(inner)=>write!(fmt,"{}",$to_string)?,
                    )*
                };
                Ok(())
            }
        }
    }
}

declare_types!(
    String -> String, inner,
);
```

However, the code results in a compiler error:

```
cannot find value `inner` in this scope
not found in this scope
```

When I hover onto `inner`, IDE shows it properly:

> [ide hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IV59.png)

Also, by expanding the macro and pasting it back, it works without any errors.

Comment: Please provide a minimal **reproducible** example. Code snippet you provided indeed does not define value `inner`.

Comment: And on the other hand you should rather use fully qualified path names in macros (especially if you want to make them public and let others use them). For example name `Display` trait as `::std::fmt::Display`.

Comment: [Macro hygiene](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/mbe-min-hygiene.html) means that the `inner` in the macro and the `inner` in the invocation are actually _two different symbols_ to the compiler. You would need the macro invocation to supply the variable name as an `ident` to use it at the invocation site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of [macro hygiene](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/mbe-min-hygiene.html), identifiers created inside the macro (like `inner` in `Self::$token (inner)`) are different from identifiers created in the calling code (like `inner` in `declare_types!(String -> String, inner);`). If you want to be able to use an identifier in the displayed expression, you will need to pass this identifier to the macro from the caller:

```
macro_rules! declare_types {
    ($($token:ident -> $inner:ty, $id: ident, $to_string:expr,)*) => {
        enum Value {
            $($token($inner),)*
        }

        impl std::fmt::Display for Value {
            fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
                match self {
                    $(
                        Self::$token($id)=>write!(fmt,"{}",$to_string)?,
                    )*
                };
                Ok(())
            }
        }
    }
}

declare_types!(
    String -> String, inner, inner,
);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=e9228dcb2ea22c6bb18b789db9b75d46)